# Android Studio don't create a structure project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-studio

I was working time ago with android studio but now i try to make a new proyect but when i creat it the structure dosent's displayed.

I don't know what is the problem.

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue. I want to create a test directory next to main, but so far (after several attempts), {project}/{app-name}/src/main is my absolute project root. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding gradle project in terminal. Use

```
$ gradle --info
```

in your project directory (*build.gradle* should be there). If there is any error, try to fix it. You should get *BUILD SUCCESSFUL*. Then **import** once again your project (selecting *build.gradle* file). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. What you need to do is to update Android Studio by going to Help -> Check for update. After Android Studio restarts you should be able to create new project with valid structure.